# access nested dictionary in Python for comparison in for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to access a nested dictionary value to compare with another dictionary's key value. I have two list of dictionaries. Look like the following:

```
params = [{'nUID': '39', 'Query': [{'MaxRecords': '40', 'OrderName': 'Forecast Placeholder - 1005', 'CustomerID': '15283'}]}]

response = [{
    'OrderID': 1028,
    'Name': 'Forecast Placeholder - 1005',
    'CustomerID': 1127}]
```

I need to compare `OrderName` value from params and `Name` from response. Here is what I have tried:

```
adpoint_key = "AdPoint_Id__c"
for index, my_dict in enumerate(test_data):
    if my_dict['DBU_Key__c'] != "AUT" and my_dict["AdPoint_Sync_Conditions__c"] != '"' and adpoint_key in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict["OpportunityID"] = my_dict["AdPoint_Id__c"]
        my_dict["CustomerID"] = my_dict["AdPoint_Customer_Id__c"]

        params = []
        params_dict = {}
        params_dict["nUID"] = "39"
        params_dict["Query"] = []
        new_dict = {} 
        new_dict["MaxRecords"] = "40"
        new_dict["OrderName"] = "Forecast Placeholder - " + my_dict["OpportunityID"]
        new_dict["CustomerID"] = my_dict["CustomerID"]
        params_dict["Query"].append(new_dict)
        params.append(params_dict)
#         print(params)

        response = client.service.GetOrders(**params[0]))

        results = []
        for a, b in zip(params, response):
            if b[0]['Name'] == a['Query'][0]['OrderName']:
                results.append(response_dict)
                print(results)
```

Error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Try this `response_dict["Name"] == params["Query"]["OrderName"]`

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Still wrong, as `params` is a **list**…

Comment: @Chique_Code, as expected, now you should fix this and it will start to work properly.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I have tried the following: `response_dict["Name"] == params["Query"]["OrderName"]` and got `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Do you expect to actually have multiple elements in **both** lists, ie. in `params` and `response`?

Comment: @Błotosmętek the data is pretty consistent. I expect the same string return every time for both of my dictionaries that are within a list. I just need to compare those values. Can't access params - Query - OrderName... If those two match - then add response dictionary to results

Comment: Do you understand my question? Do you suppose to have **several** dictionaries in one or both of the lists, or **just one dictionary** in each of the lists?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. What do you understand from that error?

Comment: I think you need to change the if statement in the for loop to `if b['Name'] == ` -- please see my example below

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.  First, create `params` and `response` as per the original post.  Note that `params` contains *nested* dicts, and `response` contains *flat* dicts.

```
# original data
params = [{'nUID': '39', 
           'Query': [{'MaxRecords': '40', 
                      'OrderName': 'Forecast Placeholder - 1005', 
                      'CustomerID': '15283'}]}]
response = [{
    'OrderID': 1028,
    'Name': 'Forecast Placeholder - 1005',
    'CustomerID': 1127}]
```

Now use zip to iterate over the lists (i.e., params, response).

```
results = list()

for p, r in zip(params, response):
    # use .get() for dictionary look-ups, to to emphasize dict vs list access
    if p.get('Query')[0].get('OrderName') == r.get('Name'):
        results.append(r)
        
print(results)
[{'OrderID': 1028, 'Name': 'Forecast Placeholder - 1005', 'CustomerID': 1127}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in the code:

1. `params` is a list as well so it should be indexed or enumberated as well.
2. the result from `param["query"]` is a list as well. You have to specify which of the dictionaries in the list you want to access (although in this case only one is present)

The following code works but I don't know if that is your intended behaviour:

```
for index, (response_dict, params_dict) in enumerate(zip(response, params)):
    if response_dict["Name"] == params_dict["Query"][0]["OrderName"]:
        results.append(response_dict)
        print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Paul I have the following error: TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
But it did return the result I suspected and I have the right dictionary being appended to results, however when I print results outside of the loop to but when I ran `print(results)` it gives me back an empty list

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that the actual structure of `params` does not match how you are accessing it.

It appears that `params` is a list of dictionaries. Then the first dictionary object contains a key named `Query` whose value is also a list of dictionaries. The first dictionary object in that list contains a key named `Order Name` with a corresponding value representing the name.

So, given the example data in `params` that you show, to retrieve the `Order Name` value `Forecast Placeholder - 1005` you would need to write:

`params[0]["Query"][0]["Order Name"]`

First retrieve the fist dictionary in the outer list.
Then retrieve the value for the key named `Query`
Then retrieve the first dictionary in the list represented by that value
Then retrieve the value for the key named `Order Name`

If this is not what you intended, then you might need to adjust the structure of `params`.

To get the query that you are currently trying to work it needs to looks like this:

`params["Query"]["OrderName"]`

and `params` needs to look like this:

```py
params = {'nUID': '39', 'Query': {'MaxRecords': '40', 'OrderName': 'Forecast Placeholder - 1005', 'CustomerID': '15283'}}
```

The error you are getting is because you are trying to index into a list with a string instead of and integer when accessing the outer list, then with the brackets how you have them you are trying to index into a string with another string.

If you need more detail let me know in the comments.

EDIT:

It seems like this should do what you want:

```py
results = []
for index, response_dict in enumerate(response):
    if response_dict["Name"] == params[0]["Query"][0]["OrderName"]:
        results.append(response_dict)
            print(results)
```

EDIT:

Since you are getting a null reference error, try using the "gravestones" technique of debugging...

```py
results = []
for index, response_dict in enumerate(response):
    print response_dict
    print response_dict["Name"]
    print params
    print params[0]
    print params[0]["Query"]
    print params[0]["Query"][0]
    print params[0]["Query"][0]["OrderName"]
    if response_dict["Name"] == params[0]["Query"][0]["OrderName"]:
        results.append(response_dict)
            print(results)
```

And see which of the print statements it dies on. Also a more complete stack trace would be extremely helpful

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not change the data type as params are parameters that are needed for the SOAP call that I am making and the response is the response of that SOAP call from a vendor. This is not changeable as well unless I change the format right in the for loop, but I am not sure to what format...

Comment: ok that makes perfect sense. we are often held hostage in this fashion. that just means that you need a bit fancier of an iteration. let me test some things and I will edit my answer.

Comment: It gives me `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` :(

Answer (score 0):

To access the value corresponding to key `'OrderName'` in the params object you must do:

```
ordername_value = params[0]['Query'][0]['OrderName']
```

to access the value corresponding to key `'Name'` in the response object you must do:

```
name_value = response[0]['Name']
```

You can then do `ordername_value == name_value`, which will return `True` if the two values are equivalent and `False` if they are not.

Comment: I got `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` on  ---> name_value = response[0]['Name']

Comment: Make sure you set `params` and `response` equal to what they are in your question. I tested my code on my end and everything works fine.

Comment: I triple checked all the variables but still receive `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` :( Can you share your code that worked for you?

Comment: ```
params = [{'nUID': '39', 'Query': [{'MaxRecords': '40', 'OrderName': 'Forecast Placeholder - 1005', 'CustomerID': '15283'}]}]

response = [{
    'OrderID': 1028,
    'Name': 'Forecast Placeholder - 1005',
    'CustomerID': 1127}]

ordername_value = params[0]['Query'][0]['OrderName']
name_value = response[0]['Name']

print(ordername_value == name_value) # returns True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change first two lines of your `for` loop:

```
for a, b in zip(params, response):
    if b[0]['Name'] == a['Query'][0]['OrderName']:
```

**Then, it'll work**

Comment: Can you please copy paste your whole code here, in comment box

Comment: ```        response = client.service.GetOrders(**params[0])
#         print(response)

        results = []
        for a, b in zip(params, response):
            if b[0]['Name'] == a['Query'][0]['OrderName']:
                results.append(response_dict)
                print(results)```

Comment: But the whole for loop is way too big to post in comments. I can edit the question with the entire for loop, there is just a lot going on lol

Comment: Just post your code starting from `for` loop. Note that in your question asked, the variable `response_dict` is used in the loop and also appended to.. which should not be done